# Copy and Paste active Word document to active Excel document using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to copy the contents of a word document (Which is open) into an active excel document by using VBA ?

I am using excel / word 2013

Comment: take a look at this question(copy from Excel to word)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310258/pasting-from-excel-into-a-word-document

Comment: Thanks i need to go from Word to Excel

Comment: you could read through that post and see if you are able to Change the provided code to your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i found the solution to my own question.

In the Excel workbook you must set up the following

'Tools -> References -> Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library'
 , or you will get a "Compile error: user-defined type not defined"

```
       Sub ClipboardToExcel()

       Dim MyData As DataObject
       Dim strClip As String


       Set MyData = New DataObject
       MyData.GetFromClipboard
       strClip = MyData.GetText

       Sheets("sheet2").Select
       Range("A1").Select
       ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= 
       _
       False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

      End Sub
```